# 'mousemove' event listener in canvas - pointer change in last rectangle only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

https://jsfiddle.net/jlpiedra90/3a7cojgw/4/

View the fiddle above for the actual code.

I'm trying to create a basic menu for a 2d canvas game. I'm content with most of it at the moment, as it works fine for what I need. However, in addition to the required 'mouseclick' event for changing the screens, I figured adding 'mousemove' would make it more clear that, when hovering over the buttons, the user was actually mousing over a button they can click.

Anyway, here's the relevant code for my Button function:

```
var Button = function(...) {
    ...        
    I.over = function(event) {
        x = event.offsetX;
        y = event.offsetY;

        if (x >= I.bX && x <= (I.bX+I.bW) && y >= I.bY && y <= (I.bY+I.bH)) {
            $('#canvas').css('cursor','pointer');
        } else {
            $('#canvas').css('cursor','auto');
        };
    };
    I.removePress = function () {
        canv.removeEventListener('mousemove', I.over, false);
        canv.removeEventListener('mousedown', I.pressed, false);
    };
    canv.addEventListener('mousemove', I.over, false);
    canv.addEventListener('mousedown', I.pressed, false);
    return I;
};
```

The event listeners are added when I push each Button 'function' to an array, GUI. The curious thing is that, while the 'mousedown' listener works properly for each individual button, the 'mousemove'  listener will only work on the last button added. Hence, mousing over the 'About' button shows the changed cursor; this is not the case for 'Help' or 'Start'. I am using jQuery to handle the cursor change.

Any help would be appreciated on rectifying this, but please note that I am trying to do as much of this as I can from scratch. I'm aware of libraries like Easel, Create etc. but would prefer not using them for this project. Thank you!

Comment: Most likely is that when you create your 2nd button, you remove the event listener for the 1st button. Then when u create the event listener for your 3rd button, you remove the event listener for the 2nd button.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3a7cojgw/6/ **Update:** After more tinkering around, it looks like the issue might not lie so much with the eventListeners for 'mousemove' but with how jQuery handles CSS changes. Replacing the cursor change with an 'alert' event shows that 'Button.over' is executing for _all buttons_ individually. While I'm somewhat relieved, I'm now left wondering how many other ways there are to change the cursor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*All* your buttons set, one after the other, the cursor property of the same node: `#canvas`.

So, let say the cursor is on the second button, here is what happens when you'll got an event:

1. Button 1 gets the event, it sets `canvas`'s cursor to `'auto'`
2. In turn, Button 2 gets the event, it sets `canvas`'s cursor to `'pointer'` (which overwrites what Button 1 did).
3. In turn, Button 3 gets the event, it sets *back* `canvas`'s cursor to `'auto'` (which overwrites what the two firsts did).

As a result, currently, only the last created button matters.

[Here is a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emyeht07/4/). I added a boolean to your Button constructor so that each button sets back `canvas`'s cursor only when the cursor was previously on top of it.

Comment: So, the 'mouseover' event is effectively listening for all the buttons I added, which is why even though it's on the first (Button1.over = true), it's not on the second (Button2.over = false) so it will be set to false. And, as nothing supersedes the third button's functionality, it will show the pointer. Makes sense now! Thanks a bunch for the help, answer + explanation!

Comment: Your welcome. BTW pay attention, I think there is a problem with your buttons when you scroll the page.

Comment: Yep, in the reply I posted to Niddro's comment I saw and corrected that. Something to do with the canvas.offset_ commands.